# Styled Text setText have bad perfomance

Tags: java, swt, styledtext

I have little problem with `StyledText`. When I use `setText()` Method and text is long, I must wait few seconds for render that text. Is there any method what can I use to speed up showing this text?

Answer (score 0):

The only optimisation you can implement is putting your `setText()` <strike>in a `Job` or</strike> in a `Runnable` to not block the UI.

Other than that, it's an API limitation from SWT.

Other suggestions:

File a bug/feature request

Search for a `StyledText`, although apparently none exist

Rethink your program. Don't you have a backup plan? Is the performance critical?

---

**Edit:**

[@greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449)

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class Test
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new Test();
    }

    private Test()
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        button.setText("Press me");

        final StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.NONE);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
        {
            @Override public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override public void run()
                    {
                        text.setText("*put very long text here*");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        shell.setSize(1000, 1000);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: `StyledText.setText()` has to be run on the UI thread, it will throw the invalid thread exception otherwise.