SWT - New TextLayout created each time text is added in StyledText
My GUI written in SWT gets slower while running.
I found - using Sleak tool - that a TextLayout instance is created each time a character is added in my StyledText instance.
Using the snippet provided by eclipse.org, I noticed the same problem.
I work on Linux Ubuntu with the last version of SWT.
You can find a little snippet after this message: run Snippet163 using Sleak to see instances of TextLayout.
package styledtext;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyleRange;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledTextLineSpacingProvider;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.DeviceData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Snippet163 {
    
    private static Display display;
    private static Shell shell;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeviceData data = new DeviceData();
        data.tracking = true;
        display = new Display(data);
        Sleak sleak = new Sleak();
        sleak.open();

        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Snippet 163");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setSize(800, 600);

        run();


        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }


    private static void run() {
        StyledText text = new StyledText (shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL );
        //text.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);   
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        
        
        /* useless ?
        text.setLineSpacingProvider(new StyledTextLineSpacingProvider() {
            public Integer getLineSpacing(int lineIndex) {
                return 5;
            }
        });     
        */
        
        text.setText("0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKLM NOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        // make 0123456789 appear bold
        StyleRange style1 = new StyleRange();
        style1.start = 0;
        style1.length = 10;
        style1.fontStyle = SWT.BOLD;
        text.setStyleRange(style1);
        // make ABCDEFGHIJKLM have a red font
        StyleRange style2 = new StyleRange();
        style2.start = 11;
        style2.length = 13;
        style2.foreground = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
        text.setStyleRange(style2);
        // make NOPQRSTUVWXYZ have a blue background
        StyleRange style3 = new StyleRange();
        style3.start = 25;
        style3.length = 13;
        style3.background = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
        text.setStyleRange(style3);
        
        
        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("insert!");
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    text.insert("Update ! " + i + "\n");
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

package styledtext;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Cursor;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.DeviceData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.FontData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

/**
 * Instructions on how to use the Sleak tool with a standlaone SWT example:
 * 
 * Modify the main method below to launch your application.
 * Run Sleak.
 * 
 */
public class Sleak {
    Display display;
    Shell shell;
    List list;
    Canvas canvas;
    Button start, stop, check;
    Text text;
    Label label;
    
    Object [] oldObjects = new Object [0];
    Error [] oldErrors = new Error [0];
    Object [] objects = new Object [0];
    Error [] errors = new Error [0];
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        DeviceData data = new DeviceData();
        data.tracking = true;
        Display display = new Display (data);
        Sleak sleak = new Sleak ();
        sleak.open ();

        while (!sleak.shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }
    
    public void open () {
        display = Display.getCurrent ();
        shell = new Shell (display);
        shell.setText ("S-Leak");
        list = new List (shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        list.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                refreshObject ();
            }
        });
        text = new Text (shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        canvas = new Canvas (shell, SWT.BORDER);
        canvas.addListener (SWT.Paint, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                paintCanvas (event);
            }
        });
        check = new Button (shell, SWT.CHECK);
        check.setText ("Stack");
        check.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                toggleStackTrace ();
            }
        });
        start = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
        start.setText ("Snap");
        start.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                refreshAll ();
            }
        });
        stop = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
        stop.setText ("Diff");
        stop.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                refreshDifference ();
            }
        });
        label = new Label (shell, SWT.BORDER);
        label.setText ("0 object(s)");
        shell.addListener (SWT.Resize, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                layout ();
            }
        });
        check.setSelection (false);
        text.setVisible (false);
        Point size = shell.getSize ();
        shell.setSize (size.x / 2, size.y / 2);
        shell.open();
    }
    
    void refreshLabel () {
        int colors = 0, cursors = 0, fonts = 0, gcs = 0, images = 0, regions = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
            Object object = objects [i];
            if (object instanceof Color) colors++;
            if (object instanceof Cursor) cursors++;
            if (object instanceof Font) fonts++;
            if (object instanceof GC) gcs++;
            if (object instanceof Image) images++;
            if (object instanceof Region) regions++;
        }
        String string = "";
        if (colors != 0) string += colors + " Color(s)\n";
        if (cursors != 0) string += cursors + " Cursor(s)\n";
        if (fonts != 0) string += fonts + " Font(s)\n";
        if (gcs != 0) string += gcs + " GC(s)\n";
        if (images != 0) string += images + " Image(s)\n";
        if (regions != 0) string += regions + " Region(s)\n";
        if (string.length () != 0) {
            string = string.substring (0, string.length () - 1);
        }
        label.setText (string);
    }
    
    void refreshDifference () {
        DeviceData info = display.getDeviceData ();
        if (!info.tracking) {
            MessageBox dialog = new MessageBox (shell, SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.OK);
            dialog.setText (shell.getText ());
            dialog.setMessage ("Warning: Device is not tracking resource allocation");
            dialog.open ();
        }
        Object [] newObjects = info.objects;
        Error [] newErrors = info.errors;
        Object [] diffObjects = new Object [newObjects.length];
        Error [] diffErrors = new Error [newErrors.length];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<newObjects.length; i++) {
            int index = 0;
            while (index < oldObjects.length) {
                if (newObjects [i] == oldObjects [index]) break;
                index++;
            }
            if (index == oldObjects.length) {
                diffObjects [count] = newObjects [i];
                diffErrors [count] = newErrors [i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        objects = new Object [count];
        errors = new Error [count];
        System.arraycopy (diffObjects, 0, objects, 0, count);
        System.arraycopy (diffErrors, 0, errors, 0, count);
        list.removeAll ();
        text.setText ("");
        canvas.redraw ();
        for (int i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
            list.add (objectName (objects [i]));
        }
        refreshLabel ();
        layout ();
    }
    
    String objectName (Object object) {
        String string = object.toString ();
        int index = string.lastIndexOf ('.');
        if (index == -1) return string;
        return string.substring (index + 1, string.length ());
    }
    
    void toggleStackTrace () {
        refreshObject ();
        layout ();
    }
    
    void paintCanvas (Event event) {
        canvas.setCursor (null);
        int index = list.getSelectionIndex ();
        if (index == -1) return;
        GC gc = event.gc;
        Object object = objects [index];
        if (object instanceof Color) {
            if (((Color)object).isDisposed ()) return;
            gc.setBackground ((Color) object);
            gc.fillRectangle (canvas.getClientArea());
            return;
        }
        if (object instanceof Cursor) {
            if (((Cursor)object).isDisposed ()) return;
            canvas.setCursor ((Cursor) object);
            return;
        }
        if (object instanceof Font) {
            if (((Font)object).isDisposed ()) return;
            gc.setFont ((Font) object);
            FontData [] array = gc.getFont ().getFontData ();
            String string = "";
            String lf = text.getLineDelimiter ();
            for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                FontData data = array [i];
                String style = "NORMAL";
                int bits = data.getStyle ();
                if (bits != 0) {
                    if ((bits & SWT.BOLD) != 0) style = "BOLD ";
                    if ((bits & SWT.ITALIC) != 0) style += "ITALIC";
                }
                string += data.getName () + " " + data.getHeight () + " " + style + lf;
            }
            gc.drawString (string, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
        if (object instanceof Image) {
            if (((Image)object).isDisposed ()) return;
            gc.drawImage ((Image) object, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
        if (object instanceof Region) {
            if (((Region)object).isDisposed ()) return;
            String string = ((Region)object).getBounds().toString();
            gc.drawString (string, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
    
    void refreshObject () {
        int index = list.getSelectionIndex ();
        if (index == -1) return;
        if (check.getSelection ()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
            PrintStream s = new PrintStream (stream);
            errors [index].printStackTrace (s);
            text.setText (stream.toString ());
            text.setVisible (true);
            canvas.setVisible (false);
        } else {
            canvas.setVisible (true);
            text.setVisible (false);
            canvas.redraw ();
        }
    }
    
    void refreshAll () {
        oldObjects = new Object [0];
        oldErrors = new Error [0];
        refreshDifference ();
        oldObjects = objects;
        oldErrors = errors;
    }
    
    void layout () {
        Rectangle rect = shell.getClientArea ();
        int width = 0;
        String [] items = list.getItems ();
        GC gc = new GC (list);
        for (int i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
            width = Math.max (width, gc.stringExtent (items [i]).x);
        }
        gc.dispose ();
        Point size1 = start.computeSize (SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
        Point size2 = stop.computeSize (SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
        Point size3 = check.computeSize (SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
        Point size4 = label.computeSize (SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
        width = Math.max (size1.x, Math.max (size2.x, Math.max (size3.x, width)));
        width = Math.max (64, Math.max (size4.x, list.computeSize (width, SWT.DEFAULT).x));
        start.setBounds (0, 0, width, size1.y);
        stop.setBounds (0, size1.y, width, size2.y);
        check.setBounds (0, size1.y + size2.y, width, size3.y);
        label.setBounds (0, rect.height - size4.y, width, size4.y);
        int height = size1.y + size2.y + size3.y;
        list.setBounds (0, height, width, rect.height - height - size4.y);
        text.setBounds (width, 0, rect.width - width, rect.height);
        canvas.setBounds (width, 0, rect.width - width, rect.height);
    }
    
}


At a quick look StyledText uses a separate TextLayout for each visible line. Up to 300 entries are cached in StyledTextRenderer

So it is normal for TextLayouts to be created (and disposed) quite often by StyledText. This should not cause performance problems.

Are you trying to fix this in the Java codebase? If yes, try starting with a profiler. Otherwise it looks like it's a known limitation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762265/styled-text-settext-have-bad-perfomance and maybe https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168557
